# How can I convert a string to a variable name in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//Admin.js

var insertAdminFeed = function(s, id, timestamp){
    var admin_att_new_key = '12345';
    var admin_att_new_key2 = 'abc';
    var admin_att_new_key3 = 'zyzyz';

    var s = 'admin_att_new_key';
    console.log(global[s]); //should print '12345'
};
exports.insertAdminFeed = insertAdminFeed;
```

I want to convert a string to a variable in node.js (I have many keys, and I don't want to write if/else statements for all of them) How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use objects instead?

Comment: You can't. This will be possible in ES6 (with symbols) very nicely but in ES5 unless you use a parser you have no way to access a variable's name from itself. You also can not iterate over all closure variables. What you should do is probably `var admin= {key:'12345',key2:'abc',key3:'zyzyzy'}` and  then use Object.keys(admin) to iterate through those keys when you need them.

Comment: Node.js modules [aren't run in the global scope](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects) like JavaScript in a browser, `var`s also scope to `function`s, and `admin_att_new_key{,2,3}` seems rather like the start of an `Array`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not really possible in JavaScript.

You'd usually use an object literal to achieve similar needs.

```
var key = 'foo';
obj[key] = 1;
obj['foo'];
```

To be thorough, it is technically possible in JS using `eval`. But really, don't do this.

```
eval("var "+ name + " = 'some value';");
eval("console.log("+ name  +")");
```

Comment: I agree that its a bad idea, but `eval(s)` (assuming `s` defined as in the question) would work - no need for the variable to also be declared in an eval.