# Node convert variable value to variable name for use in destructuring assignment

Tags: node.js, destructuring

I have a models folder with an index.js file that looks like the following:

```
'use strict';
const {Dest1} = require('./destinations/dest1');
const {Dest2} = require('./destinations/dest2');
module.exports = {Dest1, Dest2};
```

I would like to dynamically load these objects based on a condition. I was thinking it might be interesting to have a middleware function that appends a value to the request that I could use to look up the correct object. I could just dynamically load the path, but I'm curious if this is possible.

Middleware:

```
 function checkDestination(req,res,next){
     if('destination1' in req.body){
          req.path = 'Dest1'
     }
     next()
 }
```

Router:

```
router.get('/', checkDestination, (req,res)=>{
    //convert req.path to variable name here
    const {Dest1} = require('./models')     
})
```

[Symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009500/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-variable-name-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, decided to go with a hashtable or dictionary look up to avoid repeating a bunch of if statements. If the above is possible, it would be less code but this is pretty clean too.

Middleware:

```
function checkDestination(req,res,next){
     if('destination1' in req.body){
         req.destination = 'destination1'
     }
     next()
}
```

HashTable:

```
const {Dest1} = require('../models')

const destLookUp = {
    destination1:function(destObj){
        return Dest1.create({})
        .then(newDest=>return newDest})
        .catch(error=>{console.log(error)})
    }
}

module.exports = {destLookUp}
```

Router:

```
destLookUp[req.destination](destObj)
```